# Fire UILocalNotification in a specific Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I want to fire a `UILocalNotification` in a specific Date. If I use this code:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[components setHour:4];
[components setMinute:0];

NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

If now it's 3 pm this works fine, but it doesn't when, for example, it's 5 pm.

How can I set the notification fire date to "the next 4 pm" ?

Comment: :- Are you want to repeat alarm every hour automatically? How you want to set alarm?

Comment: I only want to notify the user on a specific hour that he can do things in the app. The notification shouldn't be repeated.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: As far as i understand you want to repeat notification every day at certain hour?

Comment: Nope, the notification should NOT be repeated :) If it's impossible, I'll do the way you show me..

Comment: So if you just want to fire the notification tomorrow... Try setting the weekday property in NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[components setHour:4];
[components setMinute:0];

NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
 NSLog(@"Fire date : %@",fireDate);// Today 4pm is already passed. So you wont get notification 

// You need to check if the time is already passed
if ([fireDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    // Schedule it for next day 4pm
    components.day = components.day+1;
    fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
}
NSLog(@"Fire date : %@",fireDate);
```

Comment: This seems a good idea, but what if i set 30 as components.day and it's February? Does date from components return 1st or 2nd of March?

Comment: There is no chance to set `components.day` to 30 for FEB. You are just adding one day to the present day if the date is passed. Suppose now the date is feb28 5pm after adding one to the `components.day` the day will be Mar1st not Feb29. Check by changing system time

Comment: Great, I'll try this code and if it works I'll accept your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try following code with 24 hour format:-

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date];
[components setHour:16];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];

NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
[gregorian release];    

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = newDate;
localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alarm for time : %@",newDate];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but if it's 5 pm, this code create a date earlier than that moment, the same day but an hour earlier.. Hence I believe the notification will never be shown, am I right?

Comment: @Lolloz89 :- you are right. But if you want to test it again then you can set you device time and date as you want.

Answer (score 0):

In **swift 3 - 4** you can use this for specific time local notification.

```
  func scheduleLocal() {

        let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: 2019, month: 1, day: 17, hour: 10, minute: 20)
        let yourFireDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)

        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.fireDate = yourFireDate
        notification.alertBody = "Hey you! Yeah you! Swipe to unlock!"
        notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

        guard let settings = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings else { return }

        if settings.types == .none {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Can't schedule", message: "Either we don't have permission to schedule notifications, or we haven't asked yet.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

    }
```