# UILocalNotification fires every time app opens

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have a `UILocalNotification` that fires at a certain time everyday. I made sure the `fireDate` is not `nil` and the notification fires at that time perfectly. The one problem I have is that whenever I run the app from XCode, the notification fires. I don't understand why it does that. Any input is greatly appreciated! Here is some code to go by:

```
-(void)ringTheAlarm{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    if (self.alarmSet) {

        UILocalNotification *notify = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

        notify.fireDate = self.alarmTime;
        NSLog(@"%@", notify.fireDate);
        notify.alertBody = self.alarmMessage;
        notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notify.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notify];
    }
}
```

Comment: `alarmTime` is set to the current date followed by a time chosen by the user, so for example, today's date is 08/26/2013, the time is set to 5:15 am, so at 5:15 am the notification will fire, tomorrow, it will fire again at 5:15 am

Comment: @AJ.S:it looks like you are not managing time of notification well.  use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636106/fire-uilocalnotification-in-a-specific-date